# How to two way bind data received as an array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

[image]I really have no idea on how to two way bind this array of data.
what i wanted to do is the data which i receive as a response i should be able to edit in input the input field.

sorry that i dont know how to frame this question. I could really use your help.
Thanks in advance

```
export default function EditProducts(props){

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [specs, setSpecs] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`/admin/productSpecification/specification/${props.match.params.id}`)
        .then(res => {
            setSpecs(res.data.specification)
        })
    }, [])

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        setLoading(true);
        axios.patch(`/admin/productSpecification/specification/${props.match.params.id}`, fd)
        .then(res => {
           props.history.push('/allproducts')
        })
    }


    const handleOnChange = (e, spec) => {
        let data = specs;
        data[spec] = e.target.value;
        setSpecs(data)
    }
    
  
    if(loading){
        return <Spinner/>
    }
    return(
        <Container style={{height:'95%'}} className="table-background">
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <Form.Label>Category</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text"/>  
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Form.Label>Specifications</Form.Label>
            {specs.specifications.map(spec => {
                return <Row>
                <Col>
                    <Form.Control key={spec} value={spec} onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e, spec)} type="text" />
                    <br/>        
                </Col>
            </Row>})}
            <Button onClick={handleSubmit} type="submit">Save</Button>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

```
data i get from consoling specs. 

{
    "specification": {
        "specifications": [
            "motherboard",
            "ram",
            "primaryStorage"
        ],
        "_id": "5f8eab4b05940e00178fbb84",
        "category": "product",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? It looks good to work. Have you checked it sets and state has data or not after response set

Comment: I was unable to edit the data in input field. I dont know why

Comment: data showing in input fields?

Comment: yeah basically the data i get from response i show it in a input boxes where i should be able to edit them. i'll add a screenshot

Comment: Try changing key "value" to "defaultValue" in <Form.Control>

Answer (score 2):

## Issue - State mutation

The issue is you are mutating your state when you save `specs` to `data`, mutate `data`, and then save `data` back into state.

```
const handleOnChange = (e, spec) => {
  let data = specs; // <-- data is reference to specs state object
  data[spec] = e.target.value; // <-- mutation!!
  setSpecs(data) // <-- save state reference back into state
}
```

React uses shallow object equality and when you return the same object reference react assumes the value is still the same and bails on rerendering the UI.

## Solution

You should always return a *new* state object reference. The following is an example using a functional state update to copy the previous state *then* add in the object property being updated.

```
const handleOnChange = (e, spec) => {
  setSpecs(specs => ({
    ...specs, // <-- copy previous state
    [spec]: e.target.value, // <-- overwrite specific spec key
  }))
}
```